# Sort array of objects having delimited string

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-select2

I am having select2 match pattern term like this

```
[{"id":"AB,MNO,Hello","text":"AB,MNO,Hello"},
{"id":"AC,ABZ,AR","text":"AC,ABZ,AR"},
{"id":"LM,ABE,EE","text":"LM,ABE,EE"},
{"id":"AZ,ABE,EF","text":"AZ,ABE,EF"}]
```

which is basically an array of objects having comma separated string values.

I want to sort it based on the  alphabetical order of the match(In the above case the match is **AB**)

i.e final sorted object array should be like this where String is separated by a comma is sorted individually.

```
[{"id":"AB,MNO,Hello","text":"AB,MNO,Hello"},{"id":"LM,ABE,EE","text":"LM,ABE,EE"},{"id":"AZ,ABE,EF","text":"AZ,ABE,EF"},{"id":"AC,ABZ,AR","text":"AC,ABZ,AR"}]
```

I tried by removing the comma in the string and taking the index of the match.
But it will only sort full string alphabetically.

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/madhukarhebbar/0c7bshbp/)

Comment: Those are not valid objects making it hard to determine what you are trying to do. Provide a ***runnable*** [mcve] and expected results

Comment: @charlietfl Updated. Please check it.